# want to show a loading gif on a button clicked but

Tags: javascript, html, css

having problem showing a loading gif on button clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #loading-img {
    background: url("Velocity.gif");
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
    }
    .overlay {
     background: #e9e9e9;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0.5;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
<div id="loading-img"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div>text here.</div>
<button id="button">Submit</button>
</div>
<script>
$("#button").click(function () {
$(".overlay").show();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using jQuery but did you load jquery.js script?

Comment: yeah thanx got that after the very sec i uploaded it

Comment: What exactly do you want ? If you just need a gif loading on ajax, for example, I have a simple and eficient solution.

Comment: Do you know that you may not have to use the overlay? You are able to place the loading image over the button.